# git pull does not give any conflict

Tags: git

I think I am confused and need some clarification.

My teammate pushed his changes on the repository. Now I wanted to merge my changes with his and pushed my code on the repository. So I did the following

```
git add *
git commit -m "message"
git pull origin master
```

I was expecting some conflicts to arrive at this stage but it did not showed any conflicts.

Later I did `git push origin master` on which only my code was visible on the master.
So I had to revert my commit using `git REVERT HEAD` and push again

Comment: pull is fetch+merge, probably all conflicts have been solved

Comment: What do you mean "only my code was visible on master"? Why did you revert your commit? When you merge someone else's code, it won't always result in a conflict, and that's fine.

Comment: The reverting doesn't make sense at all. Use `gitk` or similar tool to visualize the history and learn how it works.

Comment: @Cupcake By "only my code was visible on master" I meant that when I checked master's files using gitk, only my changes were visible i.e. my teammate's code was not visible. Since before pushing I had done git pull origin master which did not show any conflicts, I was expecting everyone's changes in the Master's files

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of `Bartlomiej Lewandowski`:

> pull is fetch+merge, probably all conflicts have been solved

I'm not sure why you're expecting a conflict here. Usually, `git merge` solves conflict automatically. For example, you're working on file A, commit; Your teammate made change from file B and push. When you pull change from origin, git knows that you're working separately so it merge automatically without any conflict.

Even if you're working in the same file, as long as your code doesn't step on each other (made change at the same code), then it shouldn't have conflict (you've made change at line 1~10, while your friends change line 100~200)

To make sure you've done everything correctly, you better do the following steps next time:

> 1. Commit
> 2. Pull
> 3. Check log, review auto merged code, check your commit.
> 4. After made sure everything is correct, push.

I just use normal git, not gitk but it should apply the same.